# How to mask the url in react js application?

Tags: reactjs, url

I want to mask the subpaths in my react js application .
For example : mysite.com/path1/path2 to mysite.com.
So that anywhere in url part it shows only mysite.com

Comment: What are you try ? put the code !

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!